# Counting total Paths from (0,0) to (n-1,n-1) in a n*n grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, backtracking

I am using a simple backtracking algorithm to find all the paths but it does not give the right answer. I am not able to figure out the mistake. We can move up, down, left and right from a given position.

```
    Int path(int a[][200],int n,int m,int r,int c) 
    {
        if(n == r - 1 && m == c-1) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(n >= r || m >= c || n < 0 || m < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(vis[n][m] == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            vis[n][m] = 1;
            int x = path(a,n+1,m,r,c);
            int y = path(a,n,m+1,r,c);
            int u = path(a,n-1,m,r,c);
            int v = path(a,n,m-1,r,c);
            vis[n][m] = 0;
            return (x+y+u+v);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to write a program to count the total number of paths? It's just *(2n!) / (n!)^2*, no?

Comment: Can you move back up and to the left, or are you allowed to only move right and down (this is how the question is usually asked)?

Comment: My permutations and combinations are not so strong.

Comment: only right and down or all four directions?

Comment: The way to see it's `2n choose n` is to figure out that you have to make a total of `2n` steps (`n` down, `n` right), and out of those you choose `n` steps to go down, and the other `n` you go right.

Comment: We can move in all the four directions.

Comment: "does not give the right answer". We have no idea which answer it gives ans which answer you consider right.

Comment: The code looks correct. Did you initialize `vis` to all zeros?

Answer (score 0):

To *find the paths* or *count the paths* are not exactly the same thing. I will assume you want to just count the paths (because the title of your question), and that you can only **move right** or **move down**.

For this you don't really need a matrix (representing the grid) as a parameter. The following is a simple (although not efficient) recursive solution that also will work for a n*m grid:

```
int countPaths(int m, int n) {
    if (m == 0 || n == 0)
        return 1;

    return countPaths(m-1, n) + countPaths(m, n-1); 
}
```

The mathematical solution for the general n*n grid is:

`(2n choose n) = (2*n)!/(n!*n!)`

Then, comparing results with the formula:

```
countPaths(1, 1) == 2   // (2*1)!/(1!*1!)=2

countPaths(2, 2) == 6   // (2*2)!/(2!*2!)=6

countPaths(3, 3) == 20  // (2*3)!/(3!*3!)=20
```

Your backtracking approach will give the same results, but with some considerations. For example, consider when `n=2`, you will need a 3x3 matrix (and in general a `(n+1)x(n+1)` matrix) to represent/explore (and mark with 1) all the paths for the 2x2 grid:

```
int countPaths(int a[][3],int n, int m, int r, int c) {
        if(n == r-1 && m == c-1) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(n >= r || m >= c || n < 0 || m < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(vis[n][m] == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            vis[n][m] = 1;
            int x = countPaths(a,n+1,m,r,c);
            int y = countPaths(a,n,m+1,r,c);
            vis[n][m] = 0;
            return (x+y);
        }
}
```

Then:

```
countPaths(vis, 0, 0, 3, 3) == 6  // (2*2)!/(2!*2!)=6
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.